# How To Pass JSON into asp.net MVC3 controller formatted like below

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I've read Phil's article  ( http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx ) and still can't figure out how I can take json that looks like what I have below and pass it into my controller.  I don't have much control over formatting it so I need to take it like this and get the data out of it.

```
{
  "Id":"720",
  "SponsorName":"Bay Area Association of Database Developers",
  "ImageURL":"~/Images/Sponsors/baadd.org.jpg",
  "NavigateURL":"http://baadd.org/",
  "HoverOverText":"Bay Area Association of Database Developers",
  "Comment":"xx"
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the repsonse from the server? I know it's 500 but you should get a stack trace.

Comment: can you please post code from you controller and the object you accept for your controllers input parameter.  The names of the object properties and json properties need to match up exactly.

Comment: Thanks Mrchief for fixing my format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SponsorUpdateModel
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string SponsorName {get;set;}
  public string ImageURL {get;set;}
  public string NavigateURL {get;set;}
  public string HoverOverText {get;set;}
  public string Comment {get;set;}
}


public ActionResult Update(SponsorUpdateModel model)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi Jakub,  what you suggested worked pefectly!  thanks.  I also accidentally discovered that if I list out the parameters as follows, it also works.      [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Update(int id, string comment, string hoverOverText,
            string imageURL, string navigateURL, string sponsorName, string hasCurrentCodeCampYear)
        {